# Кастомная страница логина Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Могу ли я сделать свою страницу логина, но при этом оставить метод аутентификации httpBasic()?
Не меняя её на formLogin()? Это нужно для того чтобы микроконтроллер который выступает в качестве клиента смог получить данные. Но если нужно данные поменять, это можно бы было сделать из браузера.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ банален и прост, добавил formLogin() в добавку к httpBasic();

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

LoginController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

@GetMapping
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
```

}

Правда не знаю насколько это правильно...

Answer (score 0):

Дополню предыдущий ответ:

```
login("/login")
// Не забыть указать название ваших полей в форме если они отличаются от значения по умолчанию
.usernameParameter("userName")
.passwordParameter("password")
```